# Google Cloud Storage list objects with name containing "%" return 403 error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am getting my objects by calling

```
https://<bucket>.storage.googleapis.com/?prefix=folder%2F<object name>%2F&delimiter=/&max-keys=1000
```

I have tried with other special characters like !, @, #, $, ^, &, *, (, ), etc.
For the other special characters I just encode them in the , and I get the response just fine.

For example, with object "!@" under folder, the url is:

```
https://<bucket>.storage.googleapis.com/?prefix=folder%2F%21%22%2F&delimiter=/&max-keys=1000
```

However, when I try with object names with "%" and encode the percent sign to "%25", I get the following error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidSecurity</Code> <Message>The provided security credentials are not valid.</Message><Details>Request was not signed or contained a malformed signature</Details></Error>
```

What could be causing this issue ?

**Edit**

So I have tried double encoding the percent sign such that '%' character becomes "%2525" in the request. However, in the response, the prefix is strangely "%25". After testing with more cases, it turns out a request is successful only when "%25" is followed by 2 characters both within the range of '0' and 'f', however, the response prefix would be wrong. For example, "%25ab" in the request would result in "%ab" in the response prefix.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using the XML Api.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a service side bug: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117932947

I think a workaround is to encode the percent twice. But this may start failing in the future when the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thx for ur answer, I am glad to know that this is a known issue to the Cloud Storage Engineering team.

Comment: I have tried the double encode workaround, the result is in the above "Edit". So it seems the workaround does not work, what could be another workaround?

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing is because you don't have enough permissions to access to your object.

If you're using an authentication method (APIkey, bearer, etc) make sure that they have the needed [Roles for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).

However, I can see that you're calling the objects just as a GET request. Try to [Make your objects public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) and try it again with that encoding (%25). It should work.

Hope this is helpful!